# How is the browser reading Global site tag JavaScript (gtag.js)

Tags: javascript

Hope you are doing well? Maybe you can help me out.

To enable Google Analytics on a website you need to implement the gtag.js snippet:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<GA_TRACKING_ID>"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>');
</script>
```

The documentation also tells me "It’s important to place the code snippet at the top of every page to initiate the function gtag(). You can call gtag commands everywhere on your page, as long as your commands appear below the code snippet".

So my curious mind implemented the following code snippet to see what happens:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>');
  gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_label': 'Home',
    'event_category': 'Main Menu'
  });
</script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<GA_TRACKING_ID>"></script>
```

I expected that tracking wouldn't be enabled, but I see Google Analytics traffic.

I do want to understand why GA is working fine when I call gtag() before initiation. Do you have an explanation for me?

Cheers,
Raoul

Comment: This line is the one that defines the `gtag` function, not the external script: `function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}`. Although due to JS "hoisting", it doesn't actually matter where that goes (as long as it's in the global scope). So I'm not quite sure what Google are getting at (or precisely what the external script does.)

Comment: *"I call gtag() before initiation"* – You do not…!? ‍♂️

Comment: The tracking script monitors the window.dataLayer array, and sends data to the analytics server when various browser events occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your own `function gtag() {...}`, which is really just an alias for `dataLayer.push`. The actual Google Tag Manager script loaded later on actually looks at the `window.dataLayer` array, in which all tracking actions it's supposed to perform are being stored.